# Django Form. Overwrite model field

Tags: django-forms

I've a `Model`

**MODEL**

```
from django.conf.global_settings import LANGUAGES

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=56, choices=LANGUAGES, blank=True)
```

And `Form`

**FORM**

```
class SearchForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ["title", "language"]
```

I use `crispy` to render the form and the problem is that I get `label` and `required` inherited from `Book` model. So I need to somehow inhertit the `max_length` form model fields and set new `labels` value.

**MY APPROACH**

```
class SearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Title"}), required=False, label=""
    ) 

    language = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Language"}), label=""
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ["title","language"]
```

Now there are no `labels` and `title` is no required but there is no length limit on title and LANGUAGES choices inherited from `Book` model.

How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Few seconds after post an idea came to my mind.

```
class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ["title", "language"]
    labels = {
        "title": "",
        "language": ""
    }

    widgets = {
        'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Title'}),
        'language': forms.Select(attrs={'option': 'Language'}),
    }
```

Now the only question I've is how to set the first value for `language` field. At the moment is just `-------------`.